# Google Spreadsheet paste unique logics

Tags: google-sheets

The best way to show you my question is showing you example.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-6I6vI61PoIxG4gCdNP30ycgdZmCCyeXCS56YpHwD5E/edit?usp=sharing

Basically I want to extract unique cells from Column C to Column A25, but cells A:A24 does already have the values from Column C, something like this:

```
=UNIQUE(C:C != A:24)
```

Or better:

```
=UNIQUE(C:C != A:[until reaches this formula])
```

I tried with `query()`, `unique()`, `continue()`, `filter()` but all I get is errors...

I am starting to wonder if it is possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why 18 and 16 are added in your example, as they are already in the range A2:A24. Maybe that's a mistake ? To add only the values that are not in the range A2:A24 you can try

```
=filter(C2:C6, isna(match(C2:C6,A2:A25,0)))
```

If you want the end row to be 'variable' (=whatever the row before the formula), and use an open ended range in col C, 
you can do something like

```
=filter(C2:C, len(C2:C), isna(match(C2:C, indirect("A2:A"&row()-1),0)))
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it stop when it reaches formula? "=filter(C2:C6, isna(match(C2:C6,A2:[until it reaches this cell],0)))"